# Reading and writing sockets in two threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I realize that `socket` is not thread-safe in general. What about distinguished reading and writing though? If I have exactly two threads operating on the same `socket` in parallel and thread 1 only calls `recv` while thread 2 only calls `send`, do I need to add a lock for synchronize these two or would be it safe to call a single read and a single write operation concurrently?

Comment: @h0r53 Can you be more specific? What kind of "timing" issues?

Comment: It is completely fine to have independent threads for reading and writing to the same socket within a single process. I commented on the remote process that your socket is connected to, and how it may require atomic read/writes, but you shouldn't make too many assumptions about processes outside of your control, so it should be fine.

Comment: @h0r53 Sure. I am making the assumption that, if I were to use a mutex to have only one operation be executed on the socket at once, everything would work fine. So other processes are not part of the consideration.
Do you have a source on the information that concurrent read-writes are safe? I have not found anything reliable so far.

Comment: *I realize that socket is not thread-safe in general*. Who says it's not? I say it is.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Stack Overflow answers.

Comment: It's not thread safe if you have multiple threads reading or writing to the same socket. If you have a thread that reads and a thread that writes it is fine.